# Using Relative/Absolute Path with Subdomain's Images

Tags: subdomain

This is a newbie question, I know, but I couldn't find clear answer.

My web root looks like this:

/index.html

/img

I set up subdomain img.my-domain.com, it points to /img folder

Now, in my index.html I call image located in subdomain i.e. folder img

I can do it using relative and absolute path, both are working:

src="/img/image.jpg"

src="http://img.my-domain.com/image.jpg"

My question is: is there any difference? In the context of parallel downloads concept, is the image gonna be perceived by browser as coming from subdomain in both cases?

I have a lot of images and want to serve them from 2 subdomains. However I develop locally and when the website will go online, I would have to change image links from relative to absolute in case absolute path is required.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### src="/img/image.jpg"

Will send cookies for www.my-domain.com. Won't appear as a separate domain.

### src="http://img.my-domain.com/image.jpg"

Will have separate cookies. Many websites do this to improve performance.

You should real use the relative protocol so if you need SSL, you won't get warnings. `src="//img.my-domain.com/image.jpg"`

Comment: Tnx for the reply. I prefer the relative protocol, but would also like to load resources from 2 subdomains. In those cases I will have to stick with absolute paths, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

no there isn't but the relative path is the common way.